# Button clicking area does not match the rendered button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem on my web application regarding the buttons. Sometimes, in a non consistent way, the buttons clicking area does not match where the button is displayed on the screen.

When I look at the screen everything looks fine but when I put the mouse on the button, I don't get the pointer cursor, and if I click at this point on the button, nothing happens. Yet if I move the mouse below the button, the cursor turns into a pointer and I can then click there to trigger the button action.

We have validated all of our HTML and don't have any issues left. At the moment, despite being in a complete mist, we consider that it might be the font we are using as it is loaded from FontDeck (using the Google Fonts Library to load it). We are thinking that the issue might come from there because when the font gets loaded, it creates a flash of the text which causes everything to be shifted a bit because the newly loaded font is a bit taller for the same defined size.

The major problem for us is that this issue looks intermittent (i.e. we cannot reproduce it). We have it randomly in Chrome and IE11.

Has anybody got an idea of what it could be? I have seen recently the same problem in Google Maps where the clicking area for the pins where sifted on the left under the real position of the pin.

Many thanks!

If it can help, here is a line with two buttons that we know sometimes get their clicking area shifted under the button:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 align-left">
        <button id="cancel-changes-control-setting-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" ng-click="vm.close()">Cancel changes to control settings</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 align-right">
        <button id="confirm-changes-control-setting-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="vm.confirmControlSettingBtnDisabled || vm.confirmSetting === false" ng-click="vm.submitControlSetting()">
            <img src="/Content/images/small-loader.gif" alt="loading" ng-show="vm.confirmControlSettingBtnDisabled" />
            Confirm changes
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that we are using the following frameworks and libraries: AngularJS, Bootstrap, bootstrap-UI

Comment: Provide code, then we can help...

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Comment: I have added a code sample where we are having the issue from time to time.

Comment: Your issue is not clear, yet it appears to be a CSS problem. If you do believe that the fonts from FontDeck may be causing the issue, try using a native font (for debugging purposes) and see if it works. If not, we may need to play tricks with the CSS display properties of your elements, after all, you are placing an `img` in a `button` in a `float`ed container.

Comment: Thanks, we are trying that at the moment but the bug is appearing only once every 2-3 weeks in our team of 3 QA guys. To me it looks like it is a DOM rendering issue as 99.99% of the time we don't have the problem appearing.